# EmberJs : How to pass data to a component without using a controller

Tags: ember.js

The documentation for emberjs clearly states that [you should not use controllers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/controllers/), however sometimes you need to pass data into a component that is not the model for the corresponding route. For instance in an application I am working on I want to retrieve a list of records from the store and display them in a component so the user can select them as an attribute of the model for that route.

The advice I have received on this is to either create a controller and use it to retrieve the list in question or to add the list of records as an attribute of the model for that route, but since the former is inadvisable and the latter only makes sense if the item in question is a logical part of the model's schema (and therefore should probably be in there anyway) I am left feeling confused  about how this apparently simple thing ought to be done. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Ember.RSVP.hash` in your routes model hook. When the promise resolves, the results get passed as the second param in `setupController`.

```
// This would be in a route file like app/blogs/edit/route.js

model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        blog: this.store.findRecord('blog', 1),
        categories: this.store.findAll('category'),
    });
},

setupController: function(controller, models) {
    this._super(controller, models);
    controller.set('model', models.blog);
    controller.set('categories', models.categories);
},
```

**OR**

If you wanted all the data logic to exist in the component you can inject the data store service. This goes against the DDAU mantra (data down, actions up) but IMO it's a clean, modular solution. Useful if the extra content isn't visible immediately ie: components that open modal windows.

```
// This would live within the actual component

store: Ember.inject.service(),

loadCategories: function() {
    this.get('store').findAll('category').then((categories) => {
        this.set('categories', categories);
    });
}.on('init'),
```

However, I would advise against this if the data (categories in this example) were immediately visible in the layout. Ember won't wait for these requests to complete before rendering so you would see blank spaces/whatever with the actual values loading in a half second later.

Comment: I see! That's good to know, but it still involves a controller. That's the bit I'm struggling with. Although I think that your solution would probably make things more future-proof since I can put the logic in the route at this stage and wait for Ember to tell us how to live without controllers it still seems incongruous to me that you still need them for what feels like a simple use case even though they are supposed to be getting phased out.

Comment: Updated my answer with another possibility. The first answer would live in the route, not the controller. Also controllers aren't really going anywhere. I believe they are just being rebranded as 'routable components' so I wouldn't try to avoid using them in any way. The ember way is still very much the first answer with all data requests living in the route.

Comment: How should `models` and `categories` be accessed in the component?

Answer (score 1):

just be aware that components don't know anything about outside them self. The way I would solve the problem is by creating a bridge between controller and component by passing the property that you want to access to your component.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sample-com">
  {{sample-com
    sampleRequests=sampleRequests
  }}
</script>

App.MainController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    //bridged properties that the controller must communicate between components/view
  sampleRequests: 'hello world'
});

App.SampleComComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
 sampleRequests: null
});
```

if there is a better way please feel free to suggest.

Comment: That's precisely the solution I've been using, but the problem is that Ember recommend that you avoid controllers since they are due to be deprecated. Maybe there isn't a way around it for now, and I'm suffering from Emberitis (a form of exhaustion caused by trying to keep up with all the changes in Ember). Nonetheless I feel intuitively that one ought to be able to access route attributes at the view level.

Comment: got you. We are way behind with ember. We just upgraded to ember 1.13

Comment: That's probably sensible, I'm new to Ember and trying my best to learn the right way of doing things but there's been two releases with deprecations since I started learning it only a few months ago!

Comment: 6 1/2 years later on emberjs 4.2 and we still use controllers...